# Django admin panel show ForeignKey data

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm trying to display more information in a admin panel and can't
I have two models with foreign Key
I trying show streets list and add to street name City name

```
class Street(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Street')
code = models.IntegerField()
city = models.ForeignKey('City', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = True
    db_table = 'street'

def __str__(self):
    return self.name + f'({self.city.name})'

class City(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='City')
code = models.IntegerField()

class Meta:
    managed = True
    db_table = 'city'

def __str__(self):
    return self.name+ f' ({self.code})'
```

Comment: can you show how it looks now in admin and how you want it to look like ?

Comment: At the moment it shows me a list of streets, but because cities have streets with identical names, I want to display next to a street name also the name of a city that the street is connected to
error i recive "City matching query does not exist."

Comment: Error i recive "City matching query does not exist."

Comment: `Street.city` is nullable and you're not handling the case when it is null, what do you want to happen when it's null?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your problem correctly, below code should work. without an image , i'm finding it hard to understand

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Street

class StreetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'city')

admin.site.register(Street, StreetAdmin)
```

Comment: Thanks friend for trying
I found the problem
One of the streets was connected to a city that I deleted from a database, that's why I got the error

Answer (score 0):

One of the streets was connected to a city that I deleted from a database, that's why I got the error